# Installing bbm.sty in linux

Tags: packages, installing, linux

How does one install the bbm.sty package in Linux Mint?

I followed the instructions on http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bbm/ and have generated the bbm.sty file, but I am not sure where I should put this. I do have a folder called /usr/local/share/texmf/ but if I put the file(s) there, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put the file in `~/texmf/tex/latex/bbm/` (you may have to create directories for that).  however, the fonts are distributed separately as metafont source and you'll need to install them, too; it's a long time since i've done that, but try copying all of [the font files on an archive mirror](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/bbm) into `~/texmf/fonts/bbm`

after that, i reckon it’s worth running `texhash ~/texmf` (it will still work without, but slower).

now: do you really want to do all that?  what did you want the double-struck fonts for in the first place?

Comment: Thank you. This worked! (I like bbm better than bb. It is just a personal preference.)

Answer (score 40):

### Debian derivatives

I believe the easiest way is to install the `texlive-fonts-extra` package:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

This should take care of installation on Debian derivatives such as **Ubuntu** and **Mint**.

### Other distros

For RPM-based distributions such as **Fedora**, try installing the `textlive-bbm-macros-` packages (on older versions, you may need to write `yum` instead of `dnf`):

```
sudo dnf install texlive-bbm
```

Comment: FYI `apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` tells me 'After this operation, 1,525 MB of additional disk space will be used.' I am guessing `bbm.sty` itself is much smaller!

Comment: @innisfree Try with `tlmgr install bbm` and `tlmgr install bbm-macros`

Answer (score 1):

On Mint (or Debian, Ubuntu, etc.) you can search the package database for a file with

```
apt-file search "bbm.sty"
```

This shows that the file is in the system package `texlive-fonts-extra`.

As you know, a file loaded with `\usepackage` has the extension `.sty`, a class has the extension `.cls`, and for a missing legacy font, look for a `.tfm` file.

It should also be possible to install a package to your local `texmf` folder with `tlmgr install --usermode`, and then run `mktexlsr`.

Comment: For a distro-agnostic, web-based search, this could be helpful: https://pkgs.org/search/?q=bbm.sty